# Django querysets select average and best result

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    school_class = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=klasa_choices)
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Basically I'd like to get the average score (points) and the best result with the corresponding user for each school_class . Can this be done easily? (i.e without additional computing?)

So far I've come to:

```
Quiz.objects.values('school_class').annotate(avg=Avg('points'),max=Max('points')).order_by('-avg')
```

but how do I also get the user with the best score?

Comment: I don't think it's possible within the same query.

Comment: How would the second query look like then? So far I have `Quiz.objects.all().values("user","school_class").order_by('-points')`
How do I make this only return the best?

Comment: user with max points (which you have from previous query) from given class `Quiz.objects.get(school_class=school_class, points=max)`.  However, the problem is that there may be more than one with max score, then instead of `.get()` you should use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second query. You can use the results of the first one to save on ordering your tables:

```
quizzes = Quiz.objects.values('school_class').annotate(avg=Avg('points'),max=Max('points')).order_by('-avg')

Quiz.objects.values('user','school_class').filter(points=quizzes.max)
```

If you only want one, add .latest('date'), .latest('-date'), or [0] to get just one.